# Drop files on a python script in windows10, anaconda

Tags: python

I'm trying to make `.py` files droppable on `Windows 10` after installed `anaconda`.
Actually dropping files on a python script seems to work out of the box. But it can't find the modules installed with `anaconda`. I'm new working with python on windows. Here is my code:

```
import sys

try:
    from PIL import Image
except Exception as err:
    raw_input("{}".format(err))

for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg

raw_input("Press <ENTER> to continue")
```

This tiny script above runs well from sublime but throws `No module named PIL` error when a file is dropped onto it.

Comment: You need to install `PIL` module. Type `pip install PIL` in cmd _(if you have added python to environmental variables)_ or google it.

Comment: I am guessing that you have two python installations in your computer: one is used from sublime and the other is the one you are dropping files onto. Try figuring out what sublime is using.

Comment: Or try installing from [`.whl`](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow) file. To install it , type `pip install <module.whl>`

Comment: There are two python installed, and PIL is istalled with conda. The problem is, that by dropping a file on a script, it starts the normal python installation instead using the one from conda. The question is how to setup windows to use the python installed with conda? I removed the normal python and now it simply opens up Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can install PIL via

```
pip install PIL
```

or

```
conda install -c anaconda pillow
```

You can use the latter option only if you have Anaconda installed.

Comment: I have installed PIL already with anaconda. Unfortunately, when I drop files on a script it starts another python. Since I uninstalled it, python scripts are not droppable at all. The question is how to make it accept dropped files and fire up the python installed with anaconda?